# Is NSURLRequest post to HTTPS URL Secure?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am developing a iphone native app to a client.In this i want to post users data to a client server which uses SSL. I want to know whether it is secure enough because i am posting users sensitive data.

I have read some posts on this topic here in SO.

The solution like “accepting any certificates” don't work for me because it is prone to “MITM” attacks.

I am looking for complete secure communication between client server and my native app.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you are looking for, but this might help :

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#client_certificates

NSURLRequest is limited, ASIHTTPRequest is frequently used...

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I am looking for a similar kind of  solution without the use of third party libraries because it is a client application

Comment: This is robust client side library... I don't see any reason of not using it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning ASIHTTPRequest, it is by far the best solution when working with https and I use it for client solutions all the time, there is no problem with that.

Comment: I should seek client permission before using that.

Comment: Also, the developer behind ASIHTTPRequest library has stopped working on it and suggests users to stop using it because hes stopped working on it. lol

Comment: That's not because he stopped that it will suddenly blow up or that no one will fork/maintain it... Anyway, a good practice is to define and use custom classes as a bridge to it, in case a swap is required...